# Create "smart" csv file using shell script

Tags: bash, csv

I have a txt file which has some records in the following format:

```
Name=Kevin
Age=33
Gender=M
Street=LA Road
Occupation=Service
Name=Josh
Age=22
Gender=M
Occupation=None
Name=Sarah
Street=First Avenue
Occupation=Administrator
...
```

As you can see I have a different set of properties that identify some persons, one after another, but not all of the properties may be set for all the persons.
The only property that will ALWAYS be set is the `Name` value, so I would likely use that as a separator (as every value between tho different `Name` values are surely referred to the first of the `Name` values).

I want to generate a csv file from the above file as follows

File: `output.csv` ->

```
Name;Age;Gender;Street;Occupation
Kevin;33;M;LA Road;Service
Josh;22;M;<**BLANK**>;None
Sarah;<**BLANK**>;<**BLANK**>;First Avenue;Administrator
...
```

Can you please help me out to write a shell/perl script , as I want to upload this data into a database table.

Comment: EDIT: can use only bash, sorry for the typo

Comment: What database?  Most RDMS's have tools that will allow you to load the data as it is after configuring a control file of some sort.  P.S.  Click the edit button to edit your post to fix a typo.

Comment: @Gary_W The questions says that this data is in text files.

Comment: Are you sure `Name` will always be the *first* field of the record? Why can you only use bash?

Comment: @Jordan Yes and the data they contain will be loaded into what database?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Yay reading comprehension.

Comment: @Jordan  lol no worries

Comment: It's only an MS-Excel table in the end... And yes Name will always be the first field and will always be present (for example if I have two Name parameters one after another all the properties of the first of the two Names will be BLANK).

Comment: PS: to be honest the data and even the scope of the example is fictional, cause I prefer not to share my company business online (sorry for that).
The configuration however is just the same.

Comment: So, what do you have so far?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Presumably if you're working in an environment that requires only bash scripting, you must have some notion of how to write such scripts?

Answer (score 1):

This looks simple enough for `awk`; `perl` might be overkill:

```
awk -F= 'BEGIN {OFS=";"; print "Name;Age;Gender;Street;Occupation"}
         $1=="Name"{if(name)print name,a,g,s,o;
           name=$2; a=g=s=o="<**BLANK**>"}
         $1=="Age"        {a=$2}
         $1=="Gender"     {g=$2}
         $1=="Street"     {s=$2}
         $1=="Occupation" {o=$2}
         END {if(name)print name,a,g,s,o}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a table that grows to the right as we receive new key/val pairs and grows down as we see "Name" keywords.  The advantage is that except for "Name," there is no hard-coded expectation of keywords in the script -- it just adapts and grows the table as it sees new things.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS  = "="
        OFS = ";"
        key = 1
        val = 2
        split("", head)
        split("", table)
        row = 0
        col = 0
        name = 0
        blank = "<**BLANK**>"
}
NF == 2 {
        if (!name && $key != "Name")
                table[0,head["Name"]=col++] = "Name"
        name = 1
        if (!($key in head)) {
                for (i=1; i<=row; i++)
                        table[i, col] = blank
                table[0,head[$key]=col++] = $key
        }
        if ($key == "Name") {
                row++
                for(i=0; i<col; i++)
                         table[row,i] = blank
        table[row,head[$key]] = $val
}
END {
        for (i=0; i<=row; i++) {
                if (!col)
                        break
                x = table[i,0]
                for (j=1; j<col; j++)
                        x = x OFS table[i,j]
                print x
        }
}
```

The output follows:

```
Name;Age;Gender;Street;Occupation
Kevin;33;M;LA Road;Service
Josh;22;M;<**BLANK**>;None
Sarah;<**BLANK**>;<**BLANK**>;First Avenue;Administrator
```